# Trying to call all vegan restaurants from FourSquare API

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to build a dataframe with all the vegan restaurants in London. To do this I'm trying to use the FourSquare API.

My problem is that the search_query doesn't search for the
'shortName': 'Vegetarian / Vegan'

Is anyone able to help please?

Have tried experimenting with various url alternatives and been through Foursquare documentation

```
search_query = ''
radius = 1000
limit = 5

latitude = 51.54542471977169
longitude = -0.07484153418100199

url = 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?client_id= 
{}&client_secret={}&ll={},{}&v={}&query={}&radius={}&limit={}'.format(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, latitude, longitude, version, search_query, radius, limit)

results = requests.get(url).json()
results
```

I was looking for an output that could be used to build a dataframe with 'postalCode', 'state', 'name'